# swift change section array element text or font color in tableview header

Tags: ios, swift, header, tableview

My tableview code is -

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var categories = ["Action", "Drama", "Science Fiction", "Kids", "Horror"]
   }
   extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate { }

   extension ViewController : UITableViewDataSource {
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) ->      String? {
    return categories[section]
  }

  func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return categories.count
  }



   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) ->   Int {
    return 1
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->     UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CategoryRow
    return cell
    }

 }
```

The result on the simulator is -

[image]
Now, I want the to customize the font/text of the various sections i.e.  Action, Drama, Science Fiction, Kids, Horror other than black, may be make it bigger etc. How is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `tableView(_:titleForHeaderInSection:)` method, you can't modify the UI properties of the header text.

You need to implement `tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)` and `tableView(_:heightForHeaderInSection:)` methods to get a custom UI for the header, i.e.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = categories[section]
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0, weight: .bold)
    label.textColor = .red
    label.sizeToFit()
    return label
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 50.0
}
```

Simply return a `UILabel` instance with required text attributes in `tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)`

Comment: working fine, thank you. Gave positive marks as well as selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is below function available in `UITableViewDelegate`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        <#code#>
    }
```

You would have the full control over the header of each section and customisation can be done accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In the method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) ->      String? {
return categories[section]
```

the table view uses a fixed font style for section header titles. If you want a different font style, return a custom view (for example, a UILabel object) in the delegate method tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegate method of `UITableView` [tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614901-tableview) to get custom UI for the header

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

       let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: yourTable.bounds.width, height: 40))
       let headerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: 0, width: yourTable.bounds.width, height: 40))
       headerLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
       headerLabel.textColor = .blue

       headerLabel.text = self.tableView(self.yourtableView, titleForHeaderInSection: section)
       headerLabel.sizeToFit()
       headerView.addSubview(headerLabel)

       return headerView
}
```

And height for section

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat { 

        return 30 //whatever you want

}
```